# Return token in API authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I am using Passport for API authentication. My API login function is like below.

```
public function apilogin (Request $request) {
        if( $request->is('api/*')){
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            ]);
            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422);
            }
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            if ($user) {
                if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                    $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
                    $response = ['token' => $token, "message" => "successful"];
                    return response($response, 200);
                } else {
                    $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];
                    return response($response, 422);
                }
            } else {
                $response = ["message" =>'User does not exist'];
                return response($response, 422);
            }
        } 
    }
```

But I am not getting the token. My output is like below.

[image]

How can I get token as output ?

Comment: In the user model check if you have imported `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;` not `Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;`